# How to get a button in a listView embedded in an alertDialog?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-alertdialog

What I'd like to have is that when the + button next to a name isClicked, the contact is added to a list call listDemandAccepted.

[Here is what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnEES.png)

First, I created a simple layout with a ListView, then I added items to the ListView using an Arrayadapter (an ImageButton with a TextView).

Here is the code in the activity that start when a button is clicked.

```
public void displayContact() {
    listeDemandAccepted = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    if (listeDemand.size() != 0) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(ContactListActivity.this);
        final View v1 = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.liste_add_accepted_view, null);
        final ContactRequestAdapter arrayRequestAdapter = new ContactRequestAdapter(ContactListActivity.this, listeDemand);

        builderSingle.setIcon(R.drawable.user_groupe);
        builderSingle.setTitle("Updating list");
        builderSingle.setCancelable(true);
        builderSingle.setView(v1);
        TextView textView = (TextView)v1.findViewById(R.id.name_liste);
        textView.setText("New demand by :");
        ListView listView = (ListView)v1.findViewById(R.id.liste_demand_add);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayRequestAdapter);

        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Contact contact = arrayRequestAdapter.getItem(which);
                listeDemandAccepted.add(contact);
            }

        };

        builderSingle.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(builderSingle.getContext(), "Updating", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ArrayList<Contact> listeAll = listeAccepted;
                listeAll.addAll(listeDemandAccepted);
                listeContact.addAll(listeAll);
            }
        });
        builderSingle.show();
    }
}
```

I tried several methods, but did not succeed thus far. And nothing is happening after the instruction : `listeDemandAccepted.add(contact);`

Here is the contactRequestAdapter code (that I had forgotten) :

```
public class ContactRequestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

public ContactRequestAdapter(Context ctxt, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    super(ctxt,0,contacts);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    Contact contact = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.liste_demand_adapter, parent, false);
    }
    // Lookup view for data population
    TextView checkBox = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.accept_user_checkbox);

    // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
    checkBox.setText(contact.getName());

    // Return the completed view to render on screen
    return convertView;
}
```

}`

Do you have any idea on how to help me ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define an `onClickListener` to the `listview` item (in your case it is the plus button) to be able to detect and put the "`listeDemandAccepted.add(contact)`;" in that method instead of `alogInterface.OnClickListener`.

Comment: That is something that I tried, but did not know how to reach the plus button !

Comment: @Hinko Android design principle discourages UI that contain a repeated action such as the one you have defined - the list actually need not have the + button in every list item - it could just be a list and on tap of one it could add to your business model - that is just one part of my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem, I think that you have to add an `onItemClickListener` to your ListView, and inside of the listener add your contact to ArrayList declared and in the end, **do not forget** to call

```
arrayRequestAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
```